# fatal error: call to undefined function wp_headers()

Tags: wordpress

I get error like call to undefined function wp_headers() in wp_content in my theme folder.
how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific with your error message, but likely you mean to use `wp_head()` and not `wp_headers()` in your `header.php` file.

A good place to start with learning theme development is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Is this problem related to my theme? which i have downloaded from one site.